# How do I replace the default auth.basic response with a JSON response?

Tags: json, authentication, laravel-5

I have a route group that looks like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'recipe','middleware'=>['auth.basic']], function (){
     //Some things to do
});
```

When credentials are invalid Laravel outputs "Invalid credentials." How do I override this response with my own JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

In AuthController, try this :

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {

            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
            ]);

            $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => $request->input('password')                         
            ];

            if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
            {
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())
                ->with('success', 'You are successfully logged in');
            }        

            return Response::json(array(
               'success' => false,
               'errors' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),                                 
            ));           

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at the `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`. The method `getBasicResponse()` seems to be responsible for the response on a failed login attempt (with basic auth).

```
protected function getBasicResponse()
{
    $headers = ['WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic'];

    return new Response('Invalid credentials.', 401, $headers);
}
```

How to actually overwrite it seems a little tricky though. You probably need to extend the SessionGuard Class and implement your own getBasicResponse() method. Thats the easy part, how to actually instantiate your own guard instead of the default one, I don't know yet.